# Distinção entre falo/falo/fá-lo

Tags: uso-de-palavras, pronúncia

No português existem três palavras que se escrevem quase da mesma forma. São *falo* (do verbo *falar*), *falo* (pénis/pênis, do latim *phallus*), e *fá-lo* (do ênclise *faz + o*). O meu professor disse-me que não usasse *fá-lo* porque segundo ele, a gente entendê-lo-ia como *falo* (de *phallus*) e por isso a gente já só usa *fá-lo* em textos muito formais e usa *o faz* na fala, mesmo em Portugal onde a ênclise é mais comum.

Pronunciam-se de forma diferente ou distinguem-se só por contexto? É possível os falantes nativos confundirem uma destas palavras com outra e então as evitarem?

Comment: Eu diria que é muito comum mesmo. "Faz-me este trabalho! Fá-lo tu."

Comment: @Jacinto que alteração fizeste no título?

Comment: @JorgeB. Estava _fa-lo_, corrigi para _fá-lo_.

Comment: @Jacinto Ah por isso é que não aparece nada na edição, eu já tinha editado o título, vê o histórico ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. É muito comum?! És muto erudito! A "faz-me este trabalho!" eu tendo a responder "Faz tu, meu grande *****" Estávamos a editar ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @Jacinto ah claro que também se diz isso ;) Mas eu costumo dizer bastantes vezes *fá-lo*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Fá-lo* do verbo fazer, *falo* do verbo falar  e o substantivo *falo* pronunciam-se da mesma maneira em todo o lado, mas dificilmente gerarão confusão, principalmente o substantivo com as outras. Existem no Português mais de cem substantivos que coincidem com formas de verbos, e não me lembro de alguma vez ter compreendido mal ou ter visto alguém compreender mal. Talvez brincadeiras com palavras escolhidas a dedo como *não cobres muito por esse cobre que já nada cobre* gerem alguma perplexidade inicial. Além do mais *falo* com o significado de *pénis* é pouco usado.

Eu tenho a impressão que *fá-lo* é pouco usado na linguagem informal em Portugal, mas outros portugueses exprimiram aqui a opinião contrária. E depois de consultar um [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) cheguei à conclusão que *fá-lo* é muito mais frequente, na escrita, que qualquer outro verbo na mesma conjugação (*olha-o* vem num distante segundo lugar). Isto é em parte por o verbo *fazer* ser mais comum que os outros, mas não é só isso: *fá-lo* ocorre 168 vezes em cada mil ocorrências de *fazê-lo* enquanto a média para outros verbos é só 91. Curiosamente no Brasil é o contrário: os números correspondentes são 18 para *fá-lo* e 61 para a média dos outros verbos (os outros verbos que eu vi são *trazer, dizer, tomar, apanhar, comer, ver, ouvir, escutar e olhar*). Agora isto é na escrita. Na fala poderá ser algo diferente, até porque *fá-lo*, tal como *trá-lo* e *di-lo* são formas irregulares, e há até quem não as saiba bem ou tenha crescido com formas alternativas: *faze-o, traze-o e dize-o*.

Quanto a substituir *fá-lo* por *o faz*, isso é possível no Brasil (exceto na norma culta quando a frase começa pelo verbo), mas não em Portugal. O teu professor está enganado a esse respeito. No exemplo seguinte:

> "Quem é que faz o bolo?" pergunta a Ana. "Fá-lo o Miguel, que tem jeito para bolos," sugere o Paulo.

em Portugal não é possível, ou pelo menos *nunca* ouvi, "*O faz o Miguel* ..." É possível, pelo menos informalmente, omitir o pronome e dizer "*Faz o Miguel*..." Noutros contextos, *fá-lo* pode ser substituído por *faz isso*:

> Alguém tem que que explicar a situação ao tio.
>
> O João fá-lo = o João faz isso.

Mas repito, estas alternativas a *fá-lo* não resultam do receio de confusão com o substantivo *falo*. Se fosse assim, o que é que faríamos com o *falo* de falar. Ainda por cima, neste caso a possibilidade de confusão existiria, não só na fala, mas também na escrita!

Comment: É interessante as formas trá-lo/di-lo, etc, serem consideradas eruditas.  Ao menos no asturiano, estos verbos aparecem com frequência com pronome direito enclítico: *failo* (fá-lo), *dizlo* (di-lo).  É simplesmente que os luso-falantes evitem os pronomes em geral nestas situações (seja o verbo o que for)?

Comment: Erudito é uma força de expressão (e não existe um forma "popular" alternativa). São pouco usadas na linguagem informal. Talvez por esses verbos, fazer, trazer e dizer, terem um conjugação irregular. Já com verbos regulares o a conjugação pronominal me parece mais comum _come-o_, _mata-o, apanha-o_. Mas tem em conta que outro português, @JorgeB. diz que usa _fá-lo_ frequentemente. Mas podes usá-lo à vontade, que ninguém, mas ninguém, vai pensar que estás a fazer alusões impróprias.

Comment: Se fizerem um estudo a respeito, acho que 90% da população brasileira não conhece o significado "pênis" para a palavra "falo".   Vinte milhões de brasileiros (10% da população) devem saber.

Comment: @Centaurus lol não me admiraria que se obtivesse o mesmo resultado em Portugal.

Comment: Não sei em que círculos se movem em que "fá-lo" possa alguma vez ser considerado erudito. Entre pessoas com menos educação às vezes ouve-se "faze-o" (mas é curioso que a forma mais culta é "quere-o", não "qué-lo"), mas de resto toda a gente diz "fá-lo", ou quando muito substitui por qualquer coisa como "faz isso".

Comment: @Artefacto Eu cresci no campo com os _faze-os_. Não é assim tão curioso: à norma culta _tu quere-lo_ corresponde a 'norma popular' _tu querze-o_. Há divergência quando a flexão do verbo acaba em **s** ou **z**,

Comment: @Jacinto Estava a falar da 3a pessoa (para ser análogo a "fá-lo"). "Quere-lo" é 2a pessoa.

Answer (score 8):

Primeira pergunta: pelo menos no Brasil, as três são pronunciadas exatamente da mesma maneira. Creio que o mesmo valha para Portugal, mas não tenho certeza.

No caso do português brasileiro, tanto o substantivo "falo" quanto a forma "fá-lo" são bastante incomuns em fala corriqueira, e diria que a maioria das pessoas não associaria esses sons a algo além do verbo "falar" na primeira pessoa do presente do indicativo. Dessa forma, sim, provavelmente alguma confusão pode ocorrer. Porém, acho pouco provável que "falo" fosse entendida como o substantivo, especialmente se usada num contexto onde o verbo é óbvio. Pelo contrário: se alguém usasse esse som num sentido diferente do verbo, provavelmente o faria num contexto onde o sentido desejado fosse muito evidente.

Comment: Mesmíssima coisa em Portugal.

Comment: `onde o sentido desejado fosse muito evidente`... isso foi o que ela disse!